# How to check for null value in NSNumber

Tags: iphone, null, compare, nsnumber

First off I confess my ignorance, I've learned everything I know about Objective-C in the few months I've been working on my project. I also find it utterly frustrating how Objective-C seems to complicate what would be simple matters in any other language I've worked with. This question is a case in point...

In the first run my app downloads a bunch of JSON which it uses to populate a CoreData store. I use an Obj-C/JSON library (CJSONDeserializer) to convert the JSON to NSArrays. In the JSON download for one CoreData entity there's a field containing a number (`"show_id":2`) identifying the related field in another entity if there is one or null (`"show_id":null`) otherwise. In processing that field I assign it to an NSNumber using...

```
NSNumber *shoIndex = [[item objectForKey:typeKey] objectForKey:@"show_id"];
```

I then try to check that I have a valid number before attempting to fetch & link the related record so as to not do wasteful processing where there is no related record.

Interrogating `shoIndex` with...

```
NSLog(@"shoIndex: %i, %@, %@", shoIndex, shoIndex, [shoIndex description]);
```

Gives...

```
shoIndex: 19590600, <null>, <null>
```

where the JSON value was `null` &...

```
shoIndex: 228300880, 51, 51
```

otherwise.

So far the only successful check I've made is with...

```
if (![[shoIndex description] isEqualToString:@"<null>"]) {
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Update...

Looking at it another way `shoIndex` is assigned as a `NSNumber` that sometimes contains a `NSString` value `@"<null>"`. Does Obj-C have something like an `isa` operator that I could use to check the type of the contents of `shoIndex`?

TIA, Pedro.

Comment: What makes you think that the object is an instance of `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `[shoObject class]` to get the class of an object; so, to test `shoObject`'s class, you would use

```
[shoObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
```

Once you've sorted out what markers define an empty string or NSNumber, you can create a macro. I do with this by keeping an IsEmpty macro in a file called CommonMacros.h. Here's the code:

```
//Thanks Wil
//http://wilshipley.com/blog/2005/10/pimp-my-code-interlude-free-code.html

static inline BOOL IsEmpty(id thing) {
    return thing == nil
    || ([thing isEqual:[NSNull null]]) //JS addition for coredata
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}
```

Then, after importing CommonMacros.h, you can call the function like this:

```
if (IsEmpty(shotIndex)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

This should take care of this problem, and will also work on strings, arrays, etc, as you can see from the code. Thanks to Wil Shipley!

Comment: Thanks Wil, that works a treat. Looking at the URL you gave there I think you've already helped me in other ways :)

Comment: I spoke too soon. I want to do stuff if shoIndex is not empty so I tried !IsEmpty(shoIndex) and my NSNumber flies straight though it.

Comment: Hmm, odd, that's too bad. I'll suggest adding this isEqualToString:@"<null>" test to the IsEmpty code, but of course dodging that route is the reason you asked this question in the first place.

Comment: I've done that but agree that it's just moving what I wanted to dodge.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, such as missing keys in NSUserDefaults, you get back the literal @"" as an empty string.

Here's my safe check for an NSNumber.

Note the check for it being an NSNumber occurs first because NSNumber doesn't understand isEqualToString

```
        id savedPin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"blah"];  // don't assume is created so don't type as NSNumber*
        if ( ![savedPin isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [savedPin isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

Answer (score -1):

In Objective-c, it's `nil` not `null`. So:

```
if (shotIndex != nil) {
   // its not nil
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I first tried & it didn't work. Where you see <null> in my question that is what NSLog gives for the NSNumber where the JSON item was null.

Comment: This is JSON. If the shotIndex wasn't present in the JSON data, then it would be nil. However, as Pedro said, the shotIndex was present with a value of null, and JSON parsers will give you a value of [NSNull null], not nil. Sending most messages to [NSNull null] will crash, so this is an important difference.