# Best way to test if object class is nil?

Tags: objective-c

In objective C, what is a better way of doing this:

```
if ([response class] == [nil class])
```

response is either a NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary

The code is working but I'm getting a `"Invalid receiver type 'void *'  or  "comparison of distinct Objective-C types 'Class' and 'struct NSMutableDictionary *' lacks a cast"` warning messages

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're actually looking to test `[response class]`, instead of the value of `response` itself, you'll want to use

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSNull class])
```

If you're looking to check if `response` itself is `nil`, I describe a nice way of doing this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231318/how-to-check-for-null-value-in-nsnumber/4231340#4231340) to a similar question.

Comment: It turns out hat I need to check if response itself was nil.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An object's class **can't** be `nil` unless you've botched some runtime swizzling. All valid objects must be instances of a valid class. Are you trying to do something like the following?

```
 if (!response) {
    // 'response' is nil
 } else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
    // response is an NSMutableDictionary
 } else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // response is an NSDictionary
    // (or an NSMutableDictionary if you remove the above 'if')
 }
```

Comment: The `isKindOfClass:` and `isa` stuff is right.  The rest won't work; all dictionaries are an instance of NSCFDictionary (or other private class) that are subclasses of NSMutableDictionary.  There is no way to differentiate between mutable and immutable dictionaries (very much on purpose).

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned *either NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary* and appear to be testing for an instances kind...

`isKindOfClass:` will identify whether or not the receiver is an instance of the class specified.  This includes subclasses.

Note that you cannot use this to determine if a dictionary is mutable or immutable, though, as dictionaries are instances of `NSCFDictionary` which is a subclass of `NSMutableDictionary.

This is very much on purpose.

Comment: Interesting. I can imagine that being a PITA in some cases.

Comment: Much less of a PITA than code that conditionalizes on mutability vs. immutability;  it means tons of `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: mutableDict]` inefficiencies, for a start.