# Trouble using an if within an IBAction

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, ios4, if-statement

Apologies if this is a total newbie question, I have looked around online and couldn't find a simple answer.

I'm trying to make a navigation bar button disappear if a field ("googlemap") isn't filled in my iPhone app. Thinking it would just be an if statement, I've used the following code, which resulted in the button losing all of its functionality (it calls another view) and not disappearing.

```
-(IBAction)btnMapM
{
 if (googlemap != nil)
 {

 LocationInfo *ObjLocInfo = [self.LocationInfoArr objectAtIndex:0];
 LocationMap *ObjLocationMap = [[LocationMap alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationMap" bundle:nil];
 ObjLocationMap.address =  ObjLocInfo->address;
 ObjLocationMap.latitude = ObjLocInfo->latitude;
 ObjLocationMap.longtitude = ObjLocInfo->longtitude;



 [self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjLocationMap animated:YES];
 [ObjLocationMap release];

}
}
```

Is it not as simple as I had thought? If not, I'd really appreciate it if someone has the time to point me in the right direction... :-S

Thanks,

Nic

Comment: What is the type of `googlemap`? What do you mean by ‘filled’?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "a field (`googlemap`) isn't filled in"? Is it a text field?

Comment: Sorry, it's a VARCHAR field in an SQL database, in an NSString. It normally holds address information (hence the btnMap button at the top)

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this assuming that, if a particular property is set to `nil`, you want your button to disappear. (Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231318/how-to-check-for-null-value-in-nsnumber/4231340#4231340) for a better way to check if a property is empty.)

First, make sure you've declared an outlet to the button, using

```
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

in the header file, and connected everything properly in interface builder. This includes connecting your button to the `button` outlet, and the `touchUpInside` event to your `IBAction`. Then, use this for your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (googlemap == nil) {
        [button setHidden:YES];
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Using this, your app checks the `googlemap` property when the view loads, and hides the `button` if `googlemap` is empty. Otherwise, it proceeds, business as usual.

You can go ahead and remove the `if` statement from the `IBAction`, as that method only gets called when the user presses the button. If the button's hidden, then, the method never gets called.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for this, I've spent an hour or so trying to tweak different things as it's not working (though I can't see why, looks perfectly logical)... I'll post the full outcomes tomorrow morning once I've tried again with some sleep!

Comment: Nic, are you sure you've made all of the proper connections in interface builder?

Comment: Hi Sam, I think everything is connected properly from IB. I have btnMapm, which is then declared using     -(IBAction)btnMapM; in the header file. 

But I think I've spotted why your code doesn't work with my file (which was programmed by someone else) - although the header file declares      IBOutlet UIButton *btnMap;    , it's then not used at all in the main file. 

Instead, a new button is created in    viewDidLoad    , called Bluebutton, which references my btnMapM that's created in IB.

My understanding was that this is bad practice - I guess I should declare it in the header file?

Comment: Ah -- so, btnMapM is an Action method, which means it gets called when the button gets pressed. You probably have that connected fine. You actually need to make a connection the other way! Declare the button in your header, and then go into IB and click on the "File's Owner", which should be your controller. On the outlets tab, you'll see `btnMap` -- connect that to your button. From then on, when you refer to `btnMap`, you'll be interacting with the IB object. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sam! Although I found out that my button is set up strangely (I'll post the solution which I figured using your advice below) I did have a play around with the connections in IB which I've never done before so I think I now have a better understanding of them. I'll try to buzz up your answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-(IBAction)btnMapM: (id)sender
{
  ...
```

and also @Sam Ritchie's answer.

Comment: This actually doesn't address the issue. The IBAction will work just find without taking a `sender` parameter... if it's missing, he just won't be able to do anything with the `sender`, of course. My understanding was that he wants the button to disappear, not to control it in some way once it's been pressed.

Comment: @Sam, I've had it fail before, but you're right.  This doesn't answer his question at all.  Yours is the right answer.

Comment: I actually ran into a whole slew of failures with that very same issue when using the cocos2d graphics framework, so +1 for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped answer this - it turned out that my navigation bar button was declared separately in `viewDidLoad` (btnMapm was an action method, not the actual button, which took me a while to realise) so I just edited Sam's if statement in `viewDidLoad` to make it hide as follows:

```
    if (googlemap != nil) {

        BlueButton *blueSaveButton = [[BlueButton alloc] init];
        [blueSaveButton setTitle:@"Map" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [blueSaveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMapM) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:blueSaveButton];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
        [button release];
        [blueSaveButton release];
    }
```

And figuring that out took me about three hours. Being a beginner sucks... But perhaps this will help someone else!

Thanks

Nick